# How to use value from a custom form tag

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

How can I read out and parse a value to contact form 7?
Within my form I have following html code where I need to extract "value"

```
<input id="CF7MapLocationHidden" type="hidden" array="" name="" value="5;39.751123,10.349121">
```

Basically I need to pass "39.751123,10.349121" to a mail

Answer (score 0):

Contact form 7 will read all form fields into the form (by name) and subsequently place in the email if you call them by name.  Just surround the field name with [ ].

If you do this in your HTML (as long as this code is appearing within the CF7 Form on the actual page.

```
<input id="CF7MapLocationHidden" type="hidden" name="my-field" value="5;39.751123,10.349121">
```

And then in your email tab on the Contact Form put:

`[my-field]`

It will send in your email.

[image: ScreenShot]